# Are there any google maps extension available for 2011

Tags: 2011, external-integrations

We have to build a store locator feature in our website. Wanted to check if there are any implementations for the same already available that can be leveraged.

Thanks,
Aravind

Answer (score 5):

A "store locator" feature is rather broad since this might be something you just display results on a locator page with the integration happening during or sometime after publish. Do you already have the geo-location information and/or addresses?

If you want CMS authors to select and enter this data, the [SDL Tridion R5.3/2009 Google Maps extension](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/google_maps.aspx) by Frank van Puffelen, is a good example of how a Custom Url approach can allow authors the ability to select items through a Google map.

For SDL Tridion 2011, you would want to consider updating something similar to Google Maps latest API (version 3, I believe) along with using the latest Custom Url pop-up script.

More info:

- [Documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2011_SPONE/concept_34A7EEA7E40649E79052454C70ED3431) ([requires login](http://docportal.sdl.com/sdltridion))
- [Example from Ferdinand Lugo](http://tridionnut.blogspot.com/2013/02/custom-url-tridion.html)

If you find something else or start a new version based on the existing setup, do consider contributing maybe parts of it [back to SDL Tridion World](http://sdltridionworld.com/community/extension_overview/extension_contributions.aspx).